# Find top 3 nodes with maximum relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The structure of my data base is:

```
( :node ) -[:give { money: some_int_value } ]-> ( :Org )
```

One node can have multiple relations.

I need to find top 3 nodes with the most number of relations `:give` with their property `money` holding: `vx <= money <=  vy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` should solve your problem:

```
Match ( n:node ) -[r:give { money: some_int_value } ]-> ( :Org )
RETURN n
ORDER BY count(r) DESC //Order by the number of relations each node has
LIMIT 3 //We only want the top 3 nodes
```

Comment: So the trick was to order the result and then limit it! thanks.

Comment: btw what could I do if I want to get top 3 for each Org??

Comment: for each org? I don't understand the question but to get the top X nodes, you hate to count on the property or the occurence you want to get, then you order, and you limit to get only X nodes

Comment: I mean, the match is `( n:node ) -[r:give { money: some_int_value } ]-> ( :Org )` , so i want the top 3 for every `:Org` ( have the limit 3 for each )

Comment: With versions 3.1.x+ of Neo4j, you can use APOC Procedures to [limit results per row](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/limiting-match-results-per-row/).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the label 'node', maybe use something more descriptive like `Person` for the label so the datamodel is more clear:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:give]->(o:Org)
WITH count(r) AS num, sum(r.money) AS total, p
RETURN p, num, total ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 3;
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "their property money holding: vx <= money <= vy". If you could clarify I can update my answer accordingly. You can calculate the total of the `money` properties using the `sum()` function.

**Edit**

To only include relationships with `money` property with value greater than 10 and less 25:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:give]->(o:Org)
WHERE r.money >= 10 AND r.money <= 25
WITH count(r) AS num, sum(r.money) AS total, p
RETURN p, num, total ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: Nice trick! works fine .I meant to filter the money property to match those with their money between vx and vy.

Comment: btw what could I do if I want to get top 3 for each Org??

Comment: if you want the top three Orgs, as measured by number of incoming `give` relationships: `MATCH (n:node)-[r:give]->(o:Org) WITH count(r) AS num, o RETURN o, num ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 3`